# Improve VideoWrite speed opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video, qimage

I am trying to convert a QImage into a Mat Image and write the video using Opencv VideoWrite. The problem is it takes around 40ms to write a single frame of video. So, I am not able to write the video at 60FPS. I am looking to improve the code. Currently, 2 threads are running one tries to capture QImage frames and swap rgb frames from the video and the other thread  writes the video. I am using Windows 10, 8GB RAM in the release mode and compiling in visual studio 2015 with opencv version 3.0. I am open to use opengl, Qt or directshow for the performance.

```
    VideoWrite videoWrite;
    cv::Size frameSize(1920,1080);
 videoWrite.open(filename,CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'),60, frameSize, true);


    videoWrite << cv::Mat(myImage.height(), myImage.width(), CV_8UC3, (uchar*)myImage.bits(), myImage.bytesPerLine());
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, you have not told us your OS or compiler or toolchain, whether in DEBUG or RELEASE mode, what versions of everything you are using, nor the filesystem nor type of your disk(s)....

Comment: I am using Windows 10, 8GB RAM in the release mode and compiling in the visual studio 2015 with opencv version 3.0. I am open to use opengl, Qt or directshow for the performance.